# HTTPService event listener so it triggers something when ".send" method gets data from XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, events, flex3, httpservice

Good day everybody.

I've doing a bit of "training" at working with Flex and Remote Data from XML files.

This is my HTTPService

```
<mx:HTTPService id="loginData" url="com-handler/basic.xml" showBusyCursor="true">
</mx:HTTPService>
```

I have a button and when its clicked its call a function, that calls `loginData.send` and does a little IF condition, that IF condition relies on the data returned by `loginData`.

The condition doesn't work because its called right next to the `loginData.send`, and .send method still didn't returned the values from the XML file. But if you click it a second time a second after the first click the IF condition works.

So to deal with i wanted to do a eventListener so that when `loginData.send` returned the data from the XML it fires up the IF condition. But i don't know how to do it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The send method of HTTPService returns an AsyncToken, to which you can add a Responder, as well as arbitrary data. So in the click handler of your Button:

```
var responder:IResponder = new Responder(myResultFunction, myFaultFunction)
var token:AsyncToken = myService.send();
token.addResponder(responder);
```

Additionally, the MXML can declare a result handler:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="myService" result="myResultHandler(event)"/>
```

One interesting aspect of AsyncToken is that it is a dynamic object, meaning you ca apply arbitrary properties to it:

```
var responder:IResponder = new Responder(myResultFunction, myFaultFunction)
var token:AsyncToken = myService.send();
token.addResponder(responder);
token.myArbitraryProperty = "Whatever";
token.anotherProperty = someObject;
```

Now, in the myResultFunction you can access *event.token.myArbitraryProperty* for use in conditionals or whatever you may need.

Comment: It worked pretty well. I've just added the IF condition the the result handler, and Plinn Christmas.